# Lazy Load app, sidenav charges another module

Tags: lazy-loading, angular-routerlink, mat-sidenav

In my application I use lazy load pattern. Now, the starting dashboard has a sidebar that contains buttons that, via routerlink, should call a module that loads the template into the sidenav content.
The problem is that when the template of the new module is loaded, it overlaps the sidebar and remains within its content.

`<mat-sidenav-content id="mat-sidenav-content"> <div><button style="width: min-content; justify-content: right;" class="button-toggle" mat-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()"> <mat-icon class="sidenav-toggle">menu</mat-icon> </button></div> <a id="comp-render" *ngIf="displayClients"> <app-client-list-view routerLink="/clients"></app-client-list-view> </a> <a id="comp-render" *ngIf="displayPreventive"> <app-preventive-wizard routerLink="/preventives"></app-preventive-wizard> </a> </mat-sidenav-content>`

This is my code....